# How to filter out certain links using Jsoup

Tags: java, css, text, filter, jsoup

I am creating a simple program that takes a search input from the user and the number of links that they want to receive. However, my code has 2 problems.

1. When I print out the links, it also includes links for images, news, etc... I was wondering how I could only keep links related to the search.

   ```
    String searchURL = GOOGLE_SEARCH_URL + "?q="+searchTerm+"&num="+num;
    Document doc = Jsoup.connect(searchURL).userAgent("Mozilla/5.0").get();     
    Elements results = doc.select("a[href]");
   ```

   However, filtering the document using `a[href]` includes all links on the page. I also tried using `h3.r > a` which returned no results at all and also `a > h3`, which fixed my current problem, but it would only display the title and not the actual link. Here is part of the output that I want to get rid of:

```
Title: Google
Link: https://www.google.com/?sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwifoOa-p7bvAhUDqlkKHS8fCsIQOwgC

Title: Google
Link: https://www.google.com/?num=5&output=search&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwifoOa-p7bvAhUDqlkKHS8fCsIQPAgE

Title: News
Link: https://www.google.com/search?q=java&num=5&source=lnms&tbm=nws&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwifoOa-p7bvAhUDqlkKHS8fCsIQ_AUICCgB

Title: Images
Link: https://www.google.com/search?q=java&num=5&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwifoOa-p7bvAhUDqlkKHS8fCsIQ_AUICSgC

Title: Books
Link: https://www.google.com/search?q=java&num=5&source=lnms&tbm=bks&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwifoOa-p7bvAhUDqlkKHS8fCsIQ_AUICigD

Title: Maps
Link: https://maps.google.com/maps?q=java&num=5&um=1&ie=UTF-8&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwifoOa-p7bvAhUDqlkKHS8fCsIQ_AUICygE

Title: Videos
Link: https://www.google.com/search?q=java&num=5&source=lnms&tbm=vid&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwifoOa-p7bvAhUDqlkKHS8fCsIQ_AUIDCgF
...
```

2. Because of this, I end up with many more links than the requested amount and I think it's also including the sub links to pages(ex: When you search for Java, the first link is java.com, with its sublinks, which are the download pages).

In short, I want to be able to filter out google links such as images, news, maps, shopping, etc... and only include the main links to pages.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot achieve your goal with [jsoup](https://jsoup.org/), because the HTML content returned by Google doesn't contain the search results. Everything is build from JavaScript. You can check it by running:

```
curl https://www.google.com/\?q\=stackoverflow\&num\=3 | grep stackoverflow
```

You will not find any stackoverflow URL. You can try to run the JavaScript yourself, but it will be much easier to use the Google [Programmable Search Engine](https://developers.google.com/custom-search).

Comment: Thanks for your help. What I ended up doing was creating two documents. The first one used the filter of a > h3 to get the titles, and the other one was a[href] to get all titles and their respective links. I then put all the info from the second document into a hashmap, and then I used the titles from the first document and checked if a key in the hashmap contained my title, and used the value to get its respective link. Probably not the most efficient solution, but it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

My own solution:

```
        Elements title = doc.select("a > h3");
        Elements links = doc.select("a[href]");
        
        Map<String, String> combo = new HashMap<>();

        for (Element result : links) {
            combo.put(result.text(),result.attr("abs:href"));
        }
        for (Element result : title) {
            System.out.println("Title:"+result.text());
            String temp = getSimilar(combo, result.text());
            if(temp!=null)
                System.out.println("Link:"+temp.substring(temp.indexOf("http", temp.indexOf("http") + 1),temp.indexOf("&")));
            else
                System.out.println("No link found");
            System.out.println();
        }
        
    }

    public static String getSimilar(Map<String, String> combo, String sim){
        for (Map.Entry<String,String> key : combo.entrySet()){
            if(key.getKey().contains(sim))
                return key.getValue();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: The only problem still is, is that the number of links is always slightly off.

Comment: Once you've got your links you could always store them in a Collection, like a `List<>`, instead of directly printing them out; then filter the collection to exclude some kinds of links (images, like you mention?) and limit the total number that are output.

Comment: Yup I thought about doing that as well, but there were a bunch of different things that I wanted to filter out, so I just stuck with this approach. In order to fix this problem, when I asked the user how many links they want, I multiply that number by 2(because I always get less links than what I ask for) and this cause me to get a few extra links, instead of under, so I just manually break out of my second loop when it goes over.